# I dont understand this inheritance functionality

Tags: java, inheritance, static

Consider the following illegal code :-

```
class WrongCode{
    int i;
    static int i;
}
```

Here, the compiler says that we have duplicate fields in the same class.

Now, consider the following classes in the same file.

```
class Parent{
    int i = 10;
}

class Child extends Parent{
    static int i = 100;
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String ... aaa){
        Parent ob = new Child();
        System.out.println(ob.i);   // This prints Parent's i
    }
}
```

Since the actual object is of Child, shouldn't ob refer to Child's i? And if it is refering to Parent's "i", then in a way it is also having Parent's "i" in its own class along with its own static "i" which is NOT ALLOWED.

Child static i overshadows Parent i. And Parent's i is not static, so then how is it accessed directly using instance and not className?

Comment: Try `Child ob = new Child();` to get the derived `i`.

Comment: In the Child class make i non static and see what happens? It should still print the Parent i.

Comment: @βнɛƨн Ǥʋяʋиɢ Making i non-static in Child gives the same result.

Comment: That's because ob is of type Parent and Parent also has i. To overcome that you to create a accessor method in Child for i in Child. That's because the runtime object polymorphism works in case of method and not field.

Answer (score 2):

You have instance field `i` in `Parent` class and it remain an instance field in `Child` class.

```
System.out.println(ob.i);  // must be 10
```

Have a look at - [Oracle Java Tutorial - Hiding Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is important to realize here that there is no way `System.out.println(ob.i);` could print `Child`'s `i`: it only knows that `ob` is of declared type `Parent`, not that it was instantiated with an actual `Child`. Thus, if `Parent` did not have any `i`, there would be a compile error. If parent has an `i`, this is printed.

I have seen it mentioned on SO that access of class variables via instances (i.e. `ob.i` being equivalent to `Parent.i`) should be considered a serious design flaw of Java. I agree it can be sometimes confusing. Anyway, both your parent and child could also have a non-static `i` and it need not be the same. The argument above should be applicable to reasoning which one would be printed in which situation.

Answer (score 0):

In `ob`, the `static int i` of child is never visible since `ob` is of type Parent, irrespective of how it was instantiated( base class or derived class).

That's why you have the value as **10**, that `Parent`s `i` value.

Answer (score 0):

Java lets your class have its own variables that have the same name as a variable in the parent.   But it can't just let you randomly redefine parent variables, as that would cause other stuff to break.  So what it does...when you have a variable `obj` that's declared as the parent class, even if it holds an instance of a child class, `obj.i` will refer to the parent class's `i` rather than the child's.

Answer (score 0):

When you access class member fields (instance variables) like ob.i. you'll get the results from the class that's known at compile time, not what is known at run time.  Thats why you have value as 10 which is parents value.

For method calls they are dispatched at run time to an object of the actual class the reference points.

Regarding shadowing here is what Java lang spec says:

If the class declares a field with a certain name, then the declaration of that field is said to hide any and all accessible declarations of fields with the same name in superclasses, and superinterfaces of the class.

A hidden field can be accessed by using a qualified name (if it is static)

[language spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html)

You may refer "Field Declarations" section.

Answer (score 0):

Actually its polymorphism and ob have access only to parent class fields and behaviuors if any...